# Use distinct Validation Set in Grid Search/Random Search

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search

I want to use GridSearchCV / RandomSearchCV available in skLearn for cross-validation, However, I don't want to use k fold cross-validation instead I want to use a separate distinct validation set.

How can I achieve this?